# Fairplay stops working on iOS 12.4 and 13

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, avassetresourceloaderdelegate, avcontentkeysession

I have code to play encrypted Fairplay streams from my app and it works fine prior iOS 12.4. I use `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` to get `AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest` from `resourceLoader:shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:` and then extract SPC from the request and make http request to get CKC.

But on new iOS 12.4 a loading request is been cancelling and  `resourceLoader:didCancelLoadingRequest:` is called right after `resourceLoader:shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:` and my player stays in loading state with no errors. The same behaviour on beta iOS 13. Clear streams are playable and the problem with encrypted streams only.

Has anybody faced with this problem? Should I migrate to `AVContentKeySession` to load keys?

Comment: I can personally confirm that FairPlay DRM using `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` works on 12.4. Can you update your question with your implementation? Have you tried another device? Note that FairPlay only works on a physical device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I've found a root cause of my problem. My old code has next line:

`resourceLoader.preloadsEligibleContentKeys = YES;`

and it worked OK before.

But from 12.4 it breaks playing encrypted streams from my tests. Without setting this flag all works fine: playing online/offline content and downloading so it's weird but this flag is out-of-use on new iOS versions.